# Setting new Drive Labels to a specific file using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-workspace

I want to use Google Apps Script to add a Drive Label (that already exists) to a file (that already exists).

I think I'm having a hard time getting the Request Body correct.  If I run my fileID and LabelID through the "try this method" helper [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v2/files/modifyLabels#ModifyLabelsRequest) it works, but when I try to replicate this in Google Apps Script, I'm not getting an error, but the label is not being applied and the Response Body comes back blank.

```
var fileId = 'MY FILE ID';

var test3 =Drive.newModifyLabelsRequest({
  labelModifications:[{
      labelId: 'MY LABEL ID',
    }]
});

var output = Drive.Files.modifyLabels(test3,fileId);

Logger.log(output.modifiedLabels);
```

I originally had it written as.

```
Drive.Files.modifyLabels ('FileID',Request Body);
```

but got errors about it not parsing the Json correctly and noticed that the IDE reference put the 'Resource' before the 'fileID', so I swapped them.

[image].

Couldn't find any other posts here that relate to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out on my own.

There is a method that isn't deeply referenced that doesn't show up in the IDE's helper of Google Apps Script.  The missing piece is .setLabelModifications().  It is similar to the Java referenced [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/set-label#java)

For my need the below is the correct syntax of the code.

```
var fileId = 'YOUR FILE ID';

var AddLabel =Drive.newModifyLabelsRequest()
      .setLabelModifications(
              Drive.newLabelModification()
                .setLabelId("YOUR LABEL ID")
                );


var output = Drive.Files.modifyLabels(AddLabel,fileId);


Logger.log(output.modifiedLabels);
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I have a label that also has an options list field, how do I set the value of the field at the same time?

looking at https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/set-label#java I need to call .setFieldModifications(ImmutableList.of(fieldModification)) ?