# Setting new Drive Labels With Selections to a specific file using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

The question & answer here was very helpful:
[Setting new Drive Labels to a specific file using Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76256164/22038334)

I'm looking to take this to the next level, and set a label on a known file that also has Selection. So in my case, I have these label selections and their IDs:

3ZB971298F: Archived

9745AD2361: Unclassified

I have

```
  var AddLabel = Drive.newModifyLabelsRequest()
    .setLabelModifications(
      Drive.newLabelModification()
        .setLabelId(labelId)
    );
```

And this works well to set the label that's defined by lableId. But it's not complete, because it's missing the Selection. How can I add a selection, let's assume "Archived" with the ID as above.

I've read through the documentation (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v2/files/modifyLabels#FieldModification), but not quite getting it. Thanks.

I couldn't find documentation on setting Selection. I tried the typeahead to see if something useful could come up, but no luck. There is surprisingly very little documentation specific to GAS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out the solution after some trial and error. These methods and parameters are not well documented for Apps Scripts. Please note, to acquire the field id and the field selection id, I had to fetch the label of a sample file that has the field and selection value of interest (`Drive.Files.listLabels(fileId)`) and then manually inspect the returned object to find the `fieldId` and `fieldValue` selectionId.

Here is the solution that works for me:

```js
var fileId = ""
var labelId = ""
var fieldId = ""
var fieldValue = ""

Logger.log(DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getName());

// Add Label To The File (Fields will be empty)
var AddLabel =Drive.newModifyLabelsRequest()
AddLabel.setLabelModifications(Drive.newLabelModification().setLabelId(labelId));

// Commit
var output = Drive.Files.modifyLabels(AddLabel,fileId);
Logger.log("%s",output);

// Set field of file
var fieldModification = Drive.newLabelFieldModification();
fieldModification.fieldId = fieldId;
fieldModification.setSetSelectionValues([fieldValue]);

var modifyLabelsRequest = Drive.newModifyLabelsRequest();
modifyLabelsRequest.labelModifications = Drive.newLabelModification()
modifyLabelsRequest.labelModifications.labelId = labelId;
modifyLabelsRequest.labelModifications.setFieldModifications([fieldModification]);

// Commit
var output = Drive.Files.modifyLabels(modifyLabelsRequest,fileId);
Logger.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked great.  Ironically, at about the same time you posted, I ended up getting a working solution as well, so I'll post it below for reference too!

Answer (score 1):

Wyler's answer worked great. I ended up finding this solution at about the same time, so posting it here as well:

```
 var labelId = "";
 var fieldId = "";
 var selectionId = "";

 const request = {
    "kind": "drive#modifyLabelsRequest",
    "labelModifications": [
      {
        "kind": "drive#labelModification",
        "labelId": labelId,
        "fieldModifications": [
          {
            "kind": "drive#labelFieldModification",
            "fieldId": fieldId,
            "setSelectionValues": [
              selectionId
            ],
            "unsetValues": false
          }
        ],
        "removeLabel": false
      }
    ]
  }
  var output = Drive.Files.modifyLabels(request, fileId);
  Logger.log('Label Modified output: ', output.modifiedLabels);
  Logger.log('File: ' + fileId + ' Label: ' + selectionName + '/' + selectionId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here some code that generates a constant to use when accessing the fields. Helped me a lot when using the approach described here

```
function outCode () {
    var pageToken;
    var output;
    var labelSchema = [];

    do {
      const response = DriveLabels.Labels.list(
        {
          publishedOnly: true, pageToken: pageToken,
          view: "LABEL_VIEW_FULL",
          fields: "labels/name,labels/id,labels/revisionId,labels/properties(title,description),labels/fields(id,properties(*,displayName),textOptions,integerOptions,dateOptions,selectionOptions(listOptions(maxEntries),choices(id,properties(displayName,description))),userOptions)"
        })
      pageToken = response.nextPageToken;
      labelSchema = labelSchema.concat(response.labels);

    } while (pageToken);

    console.log('Stored  %d labels in schema; you can use the following output for programming', labelSchema.length);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(labelSchema));

    output = "const LabelIds = {";

    if (labelSchema && labelSchema.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < labelSchema.length; i++) {
        output+= `$${labelSchema[i].properties.title.replace(/[^ßÜÖÄA-Z0-9]+/ig,'_')}: '${labelSchema[i].id}'`;
        
        var fields = labelSchema[i].fields;

        if (fields && fields.length > 0) {
          output+= `,_${labelSchema[i].properties.title.replace(/[^ßÜÖÄA-Z0-9]+/ig,'_')}: {`;
          for (var f = 0; f < fields.length; f++) {
            output+= f>0?',':``;
            output+= `$${fields[f].properties.displayName.replace(/[^ßÜÖÄA-Z0-9]+/ig,'_')}: '${fields[f].id}'`;

            var choices = fields[f].selectionOptions?.choices;

            if (choices && choices.length > 0) {
              output+= `,_${fields[f].properties.displayName.replace(/[^ßÜÖÄA-Z0-9]+/ig,'_')}: {`;

              for (var c = 0; c < choices.length; c++) {
                output+= c>0?',':``;
                output+= `$${choices[c].properties.displayName.replace(/[^ßÜÖÄA-Z0-9]+/ig,'_')+": '"+choices[c].id}'`;
              }

              output+= '}';
            }
            
          }
          output+= '}'+((i<labelSchema.length-1)?',':'');
        }
      }
    }

    output+= `};`;

    console.log('You can use the following output for programming:');
    console.log(output)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**